# Managing order of HTML elements when adding them using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm generating a form using `document.getElementById.innerHTML` and the form is supposed to have a submit button at last. But the form has variable number of fields which are added by clicking on a button, the problem is when a field is added it is inserted below the save button.

```
<button class="fontButton" onClick="addField()">&plus;</button>
<form id="tasksDataForm"></form>

<script>
var f = document.getElementById("tasksDataForm");
function addField() {

            var tasksDataFields = `<br/> <input type="text"> <br/>`;
<!-- I have to put this button to end of the form and all fields that are added to form should be inserted above it -->        
if(tasks.innerHTML == ''){
            tasks.innerHTML += '<input type="submit" value="Save">';  
        }

        tasks.innerHTML += tasksDataFields;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Your form can be structured. Create a `<div>` that constains the "fields" and a separate `<div>` that contains the "buttons". Then only `innerHTML` the fields `<div>`.

Comment: Alternatively, assuming that the save button always exists and you're adding fields above it, you should be able to get get the save button as an element and find its preceding sibling and insert the new field between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Randy Casburn for the suggestion, it did the trick.

```
<button class="fontButton" onClick="addField()">&plus;</button>
<form id="tasksDataForm">
  <div id="fieldsDiv"></div>
  <div id="submitDiv"></div>
</form>

<script>
var tasks = document.getElementById("fieldsDiv");
function addField() {

            var tasksDataFields = `<br/> <input type="text"> <br/>`;

            var submitDiv = document.getElementById("submitDiv");

            if(submitDiv.innerHTML == '')
               submitDiv.innerHTML += '<input type="submit" value="Save">';

            tasks.innerHTML += tasksDataFields;
        }

</script>
```